# Clicking the back button after logging out still renders my password protected page

Tags: asp.net-4.0

I'm writing a Web Application using ASP.NET 4.0 and C#. In my application when I logout the page redirects to the Default page. But when I click the back button in my browser, it goes back to the Web page that I was working even though I'm logged out.

How do I stop it doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You could set cache headers in authenticated pages to avoid them being cached downstream on the client. [Here's an article](http://geekswithblogs.net/Frez/articles/back-button-issue-after-logout-in-asp.net.aspx) you may take a look at.

So you could set the following headers on authenticated pages:

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

This could also be done in a custom HTTP module to avoid repeating the code in all pages.